# Помогите поменять код js

Tags: javascript

как выполнить точно такой же код но без использования метки?

```js
let n = 100;
abcd: for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) continue abcd;
    }
    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: А что делает этот код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так с одной переменной.

```js
let n = 100;
for (let i = 2, isSimple = true; i <= n; i++, isSimple = true) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
           isSimple = false;
           break;
        }
    }
    if (isSimple) console.log(i);
}
```

Конечно элегантнее ввести функцию

```js
let n = 100;
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  if (isPrime(i)) console.log(i);
}


function isPrime(i) {
  for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```